# Does BCP Maintain order on insert

Tags: sql-server, bcp

If I do a queryout for BCP is the order maintained when I insert using bcp to a new table?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) for the bcp.exe `ORDER` hint:

> Bulk import performance
>   is improved if the data being imported is sorted according to the
>   clustered index on the table, if any. If the data file is sorted in a
>   different order, that is other than the order of a clustered index
>   key, or if there is no clustered index on the table, the ORDER clause
>   is ignored. The column names supplied must be valid column names in
>   the destination table. By default, bcp assumes the data file is
>   unordered. For optimized bulk import, SQL Server also validates that
>   the imported data is sorted.

You should probably also read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on optimizing bulk import performance.

Answer (score 0):

Only if both the tables have the same clustered index.

When you select from the new table and expect an order, you have to use the order by clause.
Otherwise most of the time it seems to work right.

Comment: I know that the selection needs to be ordered, but if the input file is already ordered by an ordered by query... Is it processed sequentially thus maintaining order